# rxjs and loadash CommonJS or AMD dependencies optimization warnings after upgrading to Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, commonjs, angular10

I have upgraded my application from Angular 9 to Angular 10. The upgrade process has been auccessful and I am able to run the application. But when i issue the `ng serve` command, it is showing the following warnings.

```
WARNING in src\app\auth\guard\auth.guard.ts depends on 'lodash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in src\app\shared\services\api.service.ts depends on 'rxjs/Observable'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in src\app\auth\guard\auth.guard.ts depends on 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in src\app\shared\services\localforage.service.ts depends on 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in src\app\auth\guard\auth.guard.ts depends on 'rxjs/add/operator/map'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

There is a work around that some of the people are suggested by whitelisting the commonJS, but still it will cause the increase in bundle size. How can I get rid of this common JS problem and still get an optimized bundle size ?

PS: The final code with `map` operator

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, from} from 'rxjs';

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        return this.getToken().map((token: any) => {
            if ((token !==null) && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token.data)) {
               // this.proactiveTokenRefresh(token);
                return true;
            } 
            
            // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
            this.localForage.setItem('redirectUrl', state.url).then(() => {
                // Navigate to the login page
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            });
        });
}
    
private getToken(): Observable<{}> {
    const token = this.localForage.getItem('id_token');
    
    return from(token);
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

From the warnings, Below will help

- Please check all your imports from `rxjs`

```
import {Observable, fromPromise} from 'rxjs' 
import {map, forkJoin} from 'rxjs/operators'
```

Also note to pipe your operators like below

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

    import { switchMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observable, from} from 'rxjs';
    
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    
      return this.getToken().pipe(
        map((token: any) => {
          if ((token !==null) && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token.data)) {
            // this.proactiveTokenRefresh(token);
            return true;
          } 
          // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
          this.localForage.setItem('redirectUrl', state.url).then(() => {
            // Navigate to the login page
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          });
        });
      )
    }
        
    private getToken(): Observable<{}> {
        const token = this.localForage.getItem('id_token');
        
        return from(token);
    }
```

- For `lodash`, try to replace lodash functions with various ES2015 available functions

Comment: It is showing an error like this `Module '"../../../../node_modules/rxjs/operators"' has no exported member 'fromPromise'.ts(2305)`

Comment: Sorry, `import  fromPromise from rxjs`

Comment: Most of the imports I have fixed. But there is a problem with ` 'rxjs/add/operator/map'.`. It doesn't exist in the operators and still shwoing warning

Comment: Import { map } from `rxjs/operators` **not** `rxjs/add/operator/map`

Comment: when I use this I am getting the error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'`  when I try to use it

Comment: Please share the code where the operator is being used

Comment: I have updated the question and pasted the code at the end.